# Applescript - copy files from current folder to another folder

Tags: macos, directory, applescript

I'm wondering how to copy files from the same directory the applescript is running in, to a hardcoded folder on a MAC e.g.

CurrentFolder > /Applications/MyAPP/

Cheers

Ke

Answer (score 0):

```
set applescriptDir to path to me

set ASdirFolder to do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of posix path of applescriptDir

tell application "Finder" to move file "Path:To:this.file" to POSIX file baseASdir
```

This gets the path to the Applescript you are running, gets the directory folder of the Applescript and then moves whatever files you want to that location.

Comment: @Ke. It just grabs the folder name of where the AppleScript is running from, like you asked for... right?